# How to use items which don't implement PartialOrd/Ord in a BTreeMap?

Tags: serialization, rust, traits, serde

There is a third-party type `T` which doesn't implement Ord.

I need a map, with keys of type `T`, which has a deterministic serialization.

For every other type I just use `BTreeMap<X, Y>`, where `X` implements `PartialOrd` and `Ord`.

I can't implement `PartialOrd` and `Ord` for `T` as `T` is not defined in my crate.

How can I make a map from `T` to `Y`, with a deterministic serialization?

Comment: It `T` values _can_ be compared, but `T` just happens to not implement `Ord`, you can define a newtype `struct Key(T)` which implements `Ord`, and use that as the map key.

Comment: Does `T` at least implement `Eq`? Because if not, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, a newtype seems to be the only solution in the short term.

Comment: The newtype solution is also the _idiomatic_ approach, something you'd normally use in Rust in other equivalent situations. It's valuable to keep in mind that, unlike with most gc-based languages, there is no runtime cost to trivial encapsulations like newtype. Assuming release build, `Key` and `T` values will have the exact same representation in memory, and accesing `k.0.some_field` will generate the exact same assembly as accessing `t.some_field`. You might already know all this, so don't take it as me patronizing you, but people with background in gc'ed languages don't find it obvious.

Comment: Be conscious that the `Ord` implementation you write for `Key` must still be a total ordering regardless of the contained `T`s. If you implement `Ord` incorrectly, the `BTreeMap` may not work correctly (return the wrong value for a given key, fail to find or insert a value for a key, leak memory, etc.) This can happen despite not using `unsafe` (logic bugs are not memory unsafe). So be sure you adhere to the guidelines in `Ord`'s documentation about how implementations must behave.